# howto automatically connect wpa_supplicants with wpa-enterprise after reboot

Tags: pi-3, wifi

In order to connect to a WPA-enterprise network (eduroam) I currently have to do the following (I am using Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)):

Modify

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

to include

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
 post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

and I add my network information to:

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

when I restart the PI I need to kill the running wpa_supplicant:

```
ps -C wpa_supplicant
sudo kill $ProcessID

sudo rm /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
```

then I can connect to wifi by running wpa_supplicant manually:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

So my question is then:
How do I stop the network manager from starting its wpa_supplicant service and instead start the one which gets defined by /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

thanks in advance

Jesse

**EDIT**

reading through the link on setting up [WIFI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/37921#37921) it is mentioned:

> wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf in /etc/wpa_supplicant/ e.g. wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf will only be used by wlan0

so I copied my wpa_supplicant.conf to wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf and removed my modifications to `/etc/network/interfaces` and after rebooting am able to automatically connect. This is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which OS but "the network manager" for Raspbian `Jessie` and `Stretch` is `dhcpcd` any you have killed it by including `dhcp` in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Mind you it is unclear what, if anything what you have put in `/etc/network/interfaces` will actually do, as it does not correspond to ANY normal networking protocol.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Ive updated my question to include the OS in question. Thank you for the link, ill read it through. The steps I mention are what I find online for how to connect to a wpa-enterprise network. if there is another way, im happy to hear it

Comment: reading through that link on setting up [WIFI](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) it is mentioned **wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf in /etc/wpa_supplicant/ e.g. wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf will only be used by wlan0** so I copied my wpa_supplicant to wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf and removed my modifications to /etc/network/interfaces and after rebooting am able to automatically connect.